# Csv data pass Test method

Tags: java, testng, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider, data-driven-tests

I try to pass CSV data to my test method.

This is my code: CSV file has 3 columns:

1. TestNumber
2. email
3. FirstName

UserData.java

```
public class UserData {
    private String TestNumber;
    private String email;
    private String FirstName;
    
    //Getters and Setters

}
```

Dataprovider class:

```
 @DataProvider(name = "customer" )
   public static Object[][] getFilterValues() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException, InterruptedException, CsvException {
        CSVReader reader= new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader("/home/dell/scripts/TEST/Automation - CSV/src/TestData/User.csv")).
                withSkipLines(1).
                build();

        List<UserData> csv_objectList=reader.readAll().stream().map(data-> {
            UserData csvObject= new UserData();
            csvObject.setTestNumber(data[0]);
            csvObject.setEmail(data[1]);
            csvObject.setFirstName(data[2]);
            return csvObject;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());


        UserData[] cellData = csv_objectList.toArray(new UserData[csv_objectList.size()]);
        Object[][] data = new Object[cellData.length][3];

        for(int i = 0; i <cellData.length; i++) {

            data[i][0] = cellData[i].getTestNumber();
            data[i][1] = cellData[i].getEmail();
            data[i][2] = cellData[i].getFirstName();


        }
       
        return data;
    }
```

Test method:

```java
public class UserCreate extends Base {

    @Test( dataProvider = "customer", dataProviderClass = GetUserData.class)
    public  void   UserCreate (UserData data) throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println(data.getTestNumber());
    }
}
```

I tried this way to pass data. But I get this error:

```
[public void api.wapp.registation.UserCreate.UserCreate(utilities.UserData) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException] has no parameters defined but was found to be using a data provider (either explicitly specified or inherited from class level annotation).
Data provider mismatch
Method: UserCreate([Parameter{index=0, type=utilities.UserData, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
Arguments: [(utilities.UserData) utilities.UserData@301ec38b,null,null]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test method expects `UserData` as argument. But you dataprovider is providing `String, String, String`. In the data provider method, you are passing the values of the `UserData` into the object array instead of passing the `UserData` object itself.

In the data provider method, what you have to do is that, put each `UserData` object in a single `Object[]`, which would be combined to a `Object[][]`.

```java
return csv_objectList.stream()
                     .map(user -> new Object[]{ user }) // this array represents a single test case
                     .toArray(Object[][]::new);
```